# big Endian, little Endian conversion

Tags: endianness

I know, i know, it might sound very simple, but im confused.
if you have the following input

```
Data : 1100 0101 1010 1101
```

and you want to convert big-endian to little-endian, or vice versa, which of the following would you consider as a correct output?

1. `1011 0101 1010 0011`
2. `1101 1010 0101 1100`

Thanks

Comment: You can use online tools like the following: http://www.darkfader.net/toolbox/convert/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10101101 11000101

It goes by bytes, 8-bits

Comment: thank you,
it ALWAYS goes by byte? for example for 128 bits also it goes the same?